# Adding Autocomplete to Google Geocoder

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocode

After my recent success (with help from here), I wanted to finish up my script. Google agreed that it was ok to put the geocoded map result on the second page so I want to strip out the map display from my geocoding script on the first page.

I have this working here:
http://jsfiddle.net/njDvn/15/

BUT! The only thing it doesnt have is autosuggest (the google one, not a jqueryUI one). Here is some code which does demonstrate the google autosuggest:
http://jsfiddle.net/Rr5PL/63/

Now, the code that seems to enable the autosuggest is this:

```
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(address,options);
var autocompleteOptions = {types: ['geocode']};
```

I added this to my original code and unfortunatly it doesnt work! This code can be seen here:
http://jsfiddle.net/njDvn/16/

So my question is, based on my original code in my [FIRST LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/njDvn/15/), how do I enable the google autocomplete suggestions?

Any help or input you can give would be much appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an [**Autocomplete example**](http://maps.forum.nu/v3/ac.html), (US only), with Streetview included.

The key lines for creating it are:

```
var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
var options = {
    types: [],
    componentRestrictions: {country: 'us'}
};

var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

You also need to load the Places library:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
```

and the HTML:

```
<input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50" value="">
```

By the way, you don't "add autocomplete to the geocoder".The Places Autocomplete class includes geocoding capabilities.

Comment: @Marcelo Your link is dead but I wish Google's documentation was as simple as your answer here!

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript Autocomplete is part of the Google Places API, which is not loaded by default with the Google Maps API. You need to explicitly [load the Places library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#loading_the_library) when you include the Maps API by adding the parameter **`libraries=places`**:

`<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this ready demo, that does exactly what is mentioned by  Marcelo and ssorallen
http://devfestmtm.appspot.com/demos/places/autocomplete_addressform.html